# Find mean based on a fixed time duration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data in the below format.

```
index  timestamps(s)    Bytes
0       0.0               0
1       0.1               9
2       0.2               10
3       0.3               8
4       0.4               8
5       0.5               9
6       0.6               7
7       0.7               8     
8       0.8               7
9       0.9               6
```

It is in pandas data frame (however the format does not matter). I want to divide the data into smaller portions (called windows). Each portion should be of fixed duration (0.3 seconds) and then computing average of the bytes in each window. I want the start and end index of rows for each windows like below:

```
win_start_ind = [1 4 7]
win_end_ind   = [3 6 9]
```

I intend to use these indices then to compute average number of bytes in each window.

> Appreciate for python code.

Comment: It's not clear, what is your intended output, could you add that to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Galt suggests a [simple alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153103/divide-a-python-array-into-fixed-duration-parts-windowing/46153350?noredirect=1#comment79268746_46153350) that works well for your problem.

```
g = df.groupby(df['timestamps(s)']//0.3*0.3).Bytes.mean().reset_index()
```

---

A generic solution that would work for *any* date data involves `pd.to_datetime` and `pd.Grouper`.

```
df['timestamps(s)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamps(s)'], format='%S.%f')  # 1
g = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamps(s)', freq='0.3S')).Bytes\
                                                   .mean().reset_index()   # 2
g['timestamps(s)'] = g['timestamps(s)']\
                        .dt.strftime('%S.%f').astype(float) # 3
```

---

```
g    
   timestamps(s)     Bytes
0            0.0  6.333333
1            0.3  8.333333
2            0.6  7.333333
3            0.9  6.000000    

g.Bytes.values
array([ 6.33333333,  8.33333333,  7.33333333,  6.        ])
```

Comment: You can use `df.groupby(df['timestamps(s)']//0.3*0.3).Bytes.mean()` too.

Comment: @JohnGalt Good question, I didn't know that worked. Will you add an answer or shall I edit mine?

Comment: But, I'm not sure what OP really wants, question isn't very clear :)

Comment: @JohnGalt I think OP wanted something that would make life very difficult for them to produce this very result that is easily achievable... x)

Comment: Would you please see my below comments to @David to help you understand what I need to do exactly. I am working on it from last few days, but I still did not came on right track...

Comment: @MuhammadAsifKhan in case it wasn't obvious reading from my post, you want some intermediate output from which you can calculate Bytes.mean. _ive already calculated the mean for you._

Answer (score 0):

Well, not panda aware possible solution to obtain two list of indices as requested, assuming your data is accessible as a two dimensional array where the 1st dimension are rows :

```
win_start_ind = []
win_end_ind = []
last = last_nonzerobyte_idx = first_ts = None
for i, ts, byt in data : # (1)
    if not byt: continue
    if first_ts == None :
        first_ts = ts
    win_num = int((ts-first_ts) * 10 // 3) # (2)
    if win_num >= 1 or not win_start_ind:
        if win_start_ind :
            win_end_ind.append(last_nonzerobyte_idx)
        win_start_ind.append(i)
        last = win_num
        first_ts = ts
    last_nonzerobyte_idx = i
wind_end_ind.append(last_nonzerobyte_idx)
```

1. This line just loops through your array and assign its rows content to variables, you have to adapt it to your situation. You can also loop through your array and assign the complete row to a single variable, and on the next just line extract the data you want, to the needed variables. See ([dataframe
   docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) - [N-Dimensional arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) - [Indexing in NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#arrays-indexing)) to tailor this code to your needs.
2. this line is the line that tells us when a new time window starts, if it is 0 then we are still in the same time window, if it is 1, it is time to :

   1. add to `win_end_ind` the last non-zero-byte-row index
   2. add to `win_start_ind` the current index
   3. set `first_ts` to the current time stamp so that `ts-first_ts` gives us the relative time elapsed since the beginning of this time window.

Comment: @David, First thank you for your support. Look, what I want is that:  (1) The first timestamp is the start time of my first window. I save its index to win_start_ind [ ] array. (2) Then I cumsum timestamps (col#2) untill cumsum=0.3 sec (in the example data, it is index#3). So here I got my first window. (3) For this window, I want to append the index of the last timestamp to win_end_ind [ ] array. (4) Then I start form index#4 and repeat steps# 1-3.  By this process, I will get multiple windows of equal duration (# of rows may be different in each window) if timestamps intervals are not same.

Comment: Yes, I think I understood that correctly in my first solution, but before I adapt it a bit (and comment it), you can access your data as an array of rows, right ? for example : `data[1][2] == 9` correct ?

Comment: if you do a cumulative sum over the timestamps, you won't achieve the predicted result shown in your post. For example cumulative sum of timspamps at index 1,2 and 3 = 0.1+0.2+0.3=0.6.

Comment: @MuhammadAsifKhan solution little bit modified to suit your needs :)

Comment: I am still unable to figure it out. The code gives errors........ @Nicolas David, Can I have your email id please? I will send you original dataframe and code template of what I need to obtain from it..

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my questions using pandas builtin function as follow:

As i mentioned I wanted to partition my data into fixed duration windows (or bins). Be noted, that the I tested the function only with uni timestamps. (timestamps values in my question above were hypothetical for simplicity).

The solution is copied from the [Link](https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_group_data_by_time.html) as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

# Create an empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

# Create a column from the timestamps series
df['timestamps'] = timestamps

# Convert that column into a datetime datatype
df['timestamps'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamps'])

# Set the datetime column as the index
df.index = df['timestamps']

# Create a column from the numeric Bytes series
df['Bytes'] = Bytes


# Now for my original data
# Downsample the series into 30S bins and sum the values of the Bytes
# falling into a bin.

window = df.Bytes.resample('30S').sum()
```

My output:

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00    10815752
1970-01-01 00:00:30     6159960
1970-01-01 00:01:00       40270
1970-01-01 00:01:30       44196
1970-01-01 00:02:00       48084
1970-01-01 00:02:30       47147
1970-01-01 00:03:00       45279
1970-01-01 00:03:30       40574
```

In the output:

First column   ==> Time Windows for 30 seconds duration
Second column  ==> Sum of all Bytes in the 30 seconds bin

You may also try more options of the function such as mean, last etc..  For more details, read the [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

Comment: Your question ways .3, your answer says 30. Your question says mean, your answer says sum. My answer addresses your question, yours does not. Hence, The downvote.  If you want to answer another question, then ask another question and post your answer there.

Comment: No idea of using stackoverflow... I tried to tick your answer as correct now... I don't care for downvote or what so ever.. thanks all for helping me out..

Comment: I told u I'm new to this site.. what are the advantages of upvote, downvote in real life ??

Comment: Rep = respect. No one will tell you this, but that's the truth.